# Como abreviar una condición con mas de 10 If en PHP

Tags: php, funciones, condiciones

estoy haciendo un convertidor de tallas con php (seguro con otro lenguaje estaría mas fácil pero quiero hacerlo en php) y quiero que el usuario seleccione la medida inicial (US, EU, o Cm), posteriormente indique su talla y luego se imprima una tabla con la equivalencia a cada tipo de medida.

Ya lo tengo -seguramente no de la forma mas ortodoxa pero la tengo-, pero quiero saber si hay una forma de abreviar todo este proceso. Pues es muy desgastante decirle a la maquina  "6.5 US equivale a: X EU, X Cm." "7 US equivale a: X EU, X Cm", guardar esas equivalencias en una variable y luego imprimirlas en la tabla.
porque ademas aun me faltan hacer las equivalencias de EU y Cm.

Me gustaría saber si podría hacer una función o algo así que me facilite este proceso.

De antemano gracias.

Acá mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>p</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
```

```
<?php


  error_reporting(0);      

$from = $_POST['from'];
//$to = $_POST['to'];
$talla_recibida = $_POST['talla_recibida'];
//$talla_convertida = "";


if ($from == "US"){

if($talla_recibida == "6" ){

    $talla_uk = "5.5";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "38.5"; 
    $talla_cm = "23.7";


}
elseif($talla_recibida == "6.5"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "7"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "40"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.5";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "7.5"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "8"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "8.5"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "9"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "9.5"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "10"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "10.5"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "11"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "11.5"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "12"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "12.5"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "13"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }elseif($talla_recibida == "13.5"){

    $talla_uk = "6";  
    $talla_us = $talla_recibida;  
    $talla_eu = "39"; 
    $talla_cm = "24.1";


     }

}
?>








<center>

<form method="post" action="calculadora_2.php">




    En que medida esta tu talla:
    <select id="talla" name="from" class="dropdow1">
                                            <option class="list-language" value="US">US</option>
                                            <option class="list-language" value="UK">UK</option>
                                            <option class="list-language" value="EU">EU</option>
                                            <option class="list-language" value="Cm">Cm</option>
                                            </select>    
<p>   
<input type="text" placeholder="Insertar talla" name="talla_recibida">
<input type="submit" value="convertir">
</p>


</form>


 <center>
   <table>
   <tr>
   <th>US</th>
   <th>UK</th>
   <th>EU</th>
   <th>Cm</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $talla_us ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $talla_uk ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $talla_eu ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $talla_cm ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </center>    




</center>
```

Comment: Se supone que hay una fórmula para calcular las tallas. Podrías tener una función que aplique esa fórmula para devolverte la talla adecuada. Algo así: `function getTalla(num,fromT,toT) { //calcular y devolver valor}` donde `n` es el valor numérico, `fromT` es la talla actual y `toT` es la talla a la que quieres convertir. Y para usarla: `$tallaUK=getTalla(6,'us','uk');` la función te calcula a cuanto equivale `6` convertido de `us` a `uk` **usando la fórmula para ello, la cual, supongo, existe.**

Comment: Puedes usar en switch, para abreviar. La documentación oficial esta en https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 1):

En este caso recomedaria usar una base de datos, debido a la versatilidad que puede darte, si no esta dentro de tus posibidades, puedes generar una constante en la cual estaran las tallas, dentro del array que generaras, tendras que nombrar las llaves con los elementos a buscar.

Ejemplo

```
<?php

const TALLAS = [
    'USA' => [
        '6' => [
            'talla_uk' => "5.5",  
            'talla_eu' => "38.5", 
            'talla_cm' => "23.7",
        ],
        '6.5' => [
            'talla_uk' => "6",  
            'talla_eu' => "39", 
            'talla_cm' => "24.1",
        ]
    ]
];

print_r(TALLAS['USA']['6']);

print_r(TALLAS['USA']['6']['talla_uk']);
```

De esta forma podras acceder a los recursos que necesistes sin la necesidad de un IF.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando php seguramente estas usando una aplicación con base de datos. Yo lo que te sugeriría es crear una tabla en la base de datos con las equivalencias de tallas y así cuando cargue la aplicación las almaceno en un array y las manipulo desde allí para solo mostrarlas sin necesidad de calcular nada , si usas un framework estilo laravel o symfony pues eso te lo pondría mas fácil aún.

Lo pondría en base de datos por una razon, las tallas suelen ser estáticas es decir la 10 USA siempre sera la 8 Europa por poner un ejemplo , no tienes que calcular siempre que se elija algo, no son cambiantes que hoy la 10 USA equivale a 7 europa y mañana equivale a 9 europa.

No conozco mas de tu app pero si ves cosas por el estilo de woocommerce veras que suelen trabajarlo de esa manera muestras un producto con sus tallas y sus equivalencias al mismo tiempo y no haciendo calculo cada vez que el usuario selecciona algo.

Por otro lado  si necesitas tantos if encadenados la verdad es que debes replantear el código porque no es buena practica y un switch te salvaría muchas cosas pero tampoco te lo recomendaría en este caso.